# I can't sign in to vscode with Microsoft or GitHub accounts

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to sign in vscode with Microsoft or GitHub accounts, but failed.
sign in with Microsoft, the browser page:

> An error occurred while signing in: request to
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token
> failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

vscode:

> Error while turning on Settings Sync. request to
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token
> failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

sign in with GitHub, the browser page showed success but there are two error messages on vscode:

> Error while turning on Settings Sync. request to
> https://vscode-auth.github.com/token?code=somecodes&state=some-codes-some-codes-some failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

and another:

> Sign in failed: FetchError: request to
> https://vscode-auth.github.com/token?code=somecodes&state=some-codes-some-codes-some failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

My system is win10 and vscode version is the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my same issue with these steps:

1. Disable `Docker Extension`
2. Sign-in again with github or ... (sign-in OK this time)
3. Enable `Docker Extension`